# How to add a back button to a Responsive Web-Site in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, webview, responsive-design, uibutton

I created a small app using `WKWebView`, in swift that allows a user to go to a responsive web-site, the landing page has an option that allows users to go to the full company web-site, once the site page is displayed, I have no Back Button options to take you back to the previous page. How do I add a back button in swift that a User can select to get them back to the original responsive web-site page. I'm new at this and any help would be appreciated. I'm including a copy of my code (ViewController.swift).

```
       ViewController.swift
       //  wfmApp
       //
       //  Created by Stefan Sanders on 9/13/18.
       //  Copyright © 2018 Stefan Sanders. All rights reserved.
       //

    import UIKit
    import WebKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var wenView: WKWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let URLString = "https://www.wastefreemail.com/app"
        let request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:URLString)!)
        self.wenView.load(request)

        self.wenView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading" {
            if wenView.isLoading {
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = false
            } else {
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS - How to create WKWebView Back Button programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36486918/ios-how-to-create-wkwebview-back-button-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code returns to the previous page

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var wenView: WKWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let URLString = "https://www.wastefreemail.com/app"
        let request = URLRequest(url:URL(string:URLString)!)
        self.wenView.load(request)

        self.wenView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.isLoading), options: .new, context: nil)
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if keyPath == "loading" {
            if wenView.isLoading {
                activityIndicator.startAnimating()
                activityIndicator.isHidden = false
            } else {
                activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
        }
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func goBack(_ sender: Any) {
        wenView.goBack()
    }

}
```

Comment: The IBAction func you added, does that get connected to the viewController(Main Storyboard, or do I need to add a back button to the main storyboard and connect it to that back button?

Comment: You need to add a button in Main Storyboard and link it with @IBAction func

Comment: Thanks gms, but  if I add a button to the main storyboard, then the User goes to the URL location based on my code, once the they select the full version link on the Responsive web-site, they are on a web-site outside of the app, so I don't think the button will be available, because the storyboard is no longer apart of what the User will see.

Comment: gms, with a small adjustment, your recommendation was great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Wkwebview `backForwardList` you get get complete list of back and forward items, from list you can get `backItem` and you can check if backitem is not nil it mean you can go back and same as you can get `forwarditem` and can show forward button as well.For more info see this link [back forward list](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414977-backforwardlist)

Answer (score 0):

Updated with swift 5.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

override func loadView() {
    webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view = webView
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com/in/")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems =
        [ UIBarButtonItem(title: ">", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goForward)),
          UIBarButtonItem(title: "<", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))
    ]
    let loader = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    if webView.isLoading {
        
        loader.startAnimating()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: loader)
    } else {
        
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(refreshButton))
    }
}

@objc func goBack() {
    webView.goBack()
}
@objc func refreshButton() {
    navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
@objc func goForward() {
    webView.goForward()
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish Navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        title = "Demo"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(refreshButton))

    }

}
```